# Extracting content between two tags with XPath

Tags: xpath

I've just started working with XPath recently and run into a problem. Here is the code I want to extract from:

```
 <h3>Some Company</h3>
    Mainstreet 1234
 <br>
    98776, Country
 <br>
```

How would I extract the content between the closing h3 and br tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could work `h3/following-sibling::node()[not(preceding-sibling::br) and not(self::br)]` (returns "Mainstreet 1234" for me).

But I'm affraid your real xml and real needs are more complicated than provided sample so it is possible you will need to further adjust it to fit you requirements.

Answer (score 4):

Try `//h3/following-sibling::text()[following::br]`

Answer (score 3):

If your code was in the block below:

```
<par>
    <h3>Some Company</h3>
    Mainstreet 1234
    <br>
    98776, Country
    </br>
</par>
```

You will need to tell XPath to give you the text inside every par node that is after an h3 node and before a br node. 
In XPath terms this translates to:

```
//par/text()[preceding::*[name()='h3'] and following::*[name()='br']]
```

The above would search everywhere in the document for a par node. You can get more specific about the content of the h3 and/or br nodes as well:

```
//par/text()[preceding::*[name()='h3' and text()='Some Company'] and following::*[name()='br']]
```

Please let me know if the above does not resolve your problem.