# Extracting value between tags - python xpath

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to extract part of a page constructed like this:

```
<div class="entry">
     <span>Title</span>

     <h2>Title1</h2>
     <p>Content1 details</p>
     <ul>
          <li>Content1 list</li>
     </ul>
     <p>More content1 details</p>

     <h2>Title2</h2>
     <p>Content2 details</p>
     <p>More content2 details</p>
     <p>More content2 details</p>
</div>
```

I want to extract all tags between title1 and title2 to a list. And all tags after title2 to another list.

Is it possible to use some kind of regular expression with xpath? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Maybe with `beautifulsoup`?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207439/extracting-content-between-two-tags-with-xpath

Comment: Presumably you are looking for elements rather than tags. Like, you're not interested in the `</h2>` end tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Combine [`preceding-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/preceding-sibling) and [`following-sibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling) axis. Demo from the [Scrapy Shell](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
In [1]: for item in response.xpath("//*[preceding-sibling::h2 = 'Title1' and following-sibling::h2 = 'Title2']").extract():
   ...:     print(item)
   ...:     
<p>Content1 details</p>
<ul>
      <li>Content1 list</li>
</ul>
<p>More content1 details</p>
```